# Looping to play audio android studio

Tags: java, android, loops, audio, android-studio-3.0

can anyone help me to play audio with repetition?
so the audio will be played in sequence in one click

this is the code for playing audio without repetition

```
private void panggilAntrian(){
    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.nomor);
    panggil.start();
    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            cekNomor("158");
        }
    });
    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.silahkan);
            panggil.start();
            panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.loket);
                    panggil.start();
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            cekNomor("158");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

in the code there is a function to play the audio with the repetition of each digit number.
function for repeats play audio based on digit number is this

```
private void cekNomor(String kata){
    final String[] noPanggil = kata.split("(?<=\\G.{1})");
    for(i=0; i<noPanggil.length; i++){
        switch (noPanggil[i]){
            case "0":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.nol);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.nol);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "1":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.satu);
                    Log.e("SUARA", noPanggil[i]);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.satu);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "2":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.dua);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.dua);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.tiga);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.tiga);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "4":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.empat);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.empat);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "5":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.lima);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.lima);
                            Log.e("SUARA", noPanggil[i]);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "6":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.enam);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.enam);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "7":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.tujuh);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.tujuh);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "8":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.delapan);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.delapan);
                            Log.e("SUARA", noPanggil[i]);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "9":
                if(i==0){
                    panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.sembilan);
                }else{
                    panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.sembilan);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
        }
        panggil.start();
    }
}
```

the output is for check The first number () does not play anything, whereas for check The second number () only plays the first index, ie "1".
whereas both checksNumber () should both play three audio in sequence.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this using for loop because this is synchronous programming and your loop won't wait for your sound to be completed before looping again for other song.

One of the ways you can solve this is to make recursive function so that you call it again on onCompletion just with different number to start with:

Sidenote: Be aware that I didn't test this code and I'm not sure it will work, I just wanted to head you in the right direction.

```
private void cekNomor(String kata, i){
    final String[] noPanggil = kata.split("(?<=\\G.{1})");
    switch (noPanggil[i]){
        case "0":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.nol);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "1":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.satu);
                Log.e("SUARA", noPanggil[i]);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "2":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.dua);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "3":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.tiga);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "4":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.empat);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "5":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.lima);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "6":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.enam);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);;
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "7":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.tujuh);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "8":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.delapan);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case "9":
            if(i==0){
                panggil = MediaPlayer.create(AntrianLoket.this, R.raw.sembilan);
            }else{
                panggil.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        cekNomor(String kata, ++i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
    }
    panggil.start();
}
```

Comment: thanks, my teacher has also suggested to use recursive function but I do not know how to convert this code into recursive

Comment: @RPH I converted it for you. Or at least I hope I did. Try it out! :)

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can do it for me :)

Comment: @RPH I already did in my answer. Look for the changes in code! :)

Comment: I only see changes in case "9" but I do not understand

Comment: @RPH I removed your for loop and all code you had in onCompletion methods. I added new argument for your cekNomor method that signals what song to play. In your onCompletion methods I added code that calls again cekNomor method but just with variable i+1 (next song from current). It will finish when i is greater than 9 because there is no switch case for that i and it will not call it again. When you want to start songs playing just call method cekNomor("some string", 0);

Comment: @RPH No problem, you can mark my answer as correct one so you question appears as closed/answered.